# Codedeploy fails to run on freshly scaled VM

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I have codedeploy setup to deploy to an autoscaling group.  I also have a jenkins build setup to build and deploy to code deploy.

When I use the jenkins box to deploy to codedeploy, every instance within the autoscaling group gets deployed to and everything works great.

However, when I tell the autoscaling group to bump the desired number of instances up to +1, that new instance fails to pickup the deployment from codedeploy.  It has the codedeploy-agent service installed and it is running.

Any ideas for help with debugging this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, I wasn't being patient enough.  Sometimes it just takes time--everything was setup right.